# Unable to start liberty profile in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, websphere-liberty

I have eclipse of Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)
Build id: 20161208-0600.I added liberty server profile in eclipse.The server starts and then eclipse stops the server immediately.Couldnt find any logs for this issue.
I took the eclipse zip from my collegue, for them it works without any issue.An pointer would help .Thank you

Comment: there should be a project in your eclipse workspace corresponding to the liberty install you configured with eclipse.  From there you can look at `usr/servers/<serverName>/logs/messages.log` for any possible errors that are happening and causing the server to shutdown immediately.  If you don't find anything there, perhaps try upgrading to a newer version of eclipse?  Neon is quite old.

Comment: What OS? Where on the filesystem is Liberty installed? Do you run Eclipse as an "administrative" user? Certain OS install locations aren't writeable by Eclipse if you don't run it as root/Administrator, although when this happens it seems to give appropriate error messages.

Comment: Windows 7 .Liberty filesystem is  in d:/ drive.I run eclipse as administrator

Comment: Now, really, why taket a zip from Friends... Its just a simple installation and you get fresh, clean and up2date version... Check with them if the wlp runtime binaries are included in the zip. And make sure you use same paths as they do

Comment: That last comment is incoherent as written, consider editing.